# According to the Kirchhoff's law, what's the ratio between currents in output branches of a node?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

How the current distribute in branches of a node in a circuit?

Is it randomly?

Can it be zero in an output branch when all branches have ~same physical features?

For example, suppose the current as 100 electrons that arrives to a node with two output directions. Both routes have are the ~same. How many of these 100e will go through the route 1?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of current that goes on either branch is dependent upon the resistance and any voltage potentials of the branch.

Kirchhoff's law states that the same amount of current that enters a node, must leave the node.